# Combobox in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying populate the dropdown using following code in MS Access VBA

```
strSQL = "Select BankID, BankName from tblBank"
Me.cmbBank.RowSource = strSQL
BoundColumn = 2
Me.cmbBank.Requery
```

but this shows BankID records and not showing BankName. Am I missing anything? is there any way to show Please select Bank with value bind as -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are missing the column count and column widths properties, so make sure those are properly set. The following code hides the BankId (column width = 0). If you want both displayed, just change the 0 to a 1. **EDIT** to show the prompt as a header to the list, the following will work but the sql string needs to be modified to change the column name. You may need to adjust the column width value so the entire header is visible:

```
strSQL = "Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"
With Me.cmbBank
  .RowSource = strSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 2
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .Requery
End With
```

If you don't like the header, you can use a label object with a static string next to the combobox.

**Edit 2:**
If you want to show the header in the combobox before the list opens, I think the only option is to force the value in the combobox, which would mean that the `LimitToList` property must be set to false. Unfortunately, that leaves the user entry unvalidated and free to enter whatever they please. Here's how that would work:

```
strSQL = "Select BankID, BankName As [Please Select Bank] from tblBank"
With Me.cmbBank
  .RowSource = strSQL
  .ColumnCount = 2
  .BoundColumn = 2
  .ColumnWidths = "0in.;1in."
  .ColumnHeads = True
  .LimitToList = False
  .Requery
  .Value = "Please Select Bank"
End With
```

[MSDN Column Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196029.aspx)

[MSDN Column Width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834480.aspx)

Comment: You were missing `End With`. Can you tell the property name to be used to show Please select Bank ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Try this out. You can use the `ColumnHeads` property to show the column names at the top of the list, but I am unclear whether this is what you want.

Comment: is there any way to stop entering the text in combobox?

Comment: I don't believe so. Maybe with some reference libraries and a public function you could get it to work. Combos are designed to be a combination between a textbox and a listbox. If you don't like the textbox behavior, try using a listbox control instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913664/populate-data-entry-textbox-from-query-in-vba-ms-access